# saving blobs in mysql with visual basic

Tags: mysql, sql, winforms, visual-studio, vba

I have a pdf file which I convert into byte but it says:

```
There was an error: Invalid data type
```

I don't know if I'm doing it wrong, it's possible to save a pdf this way?
My database is this

```
CREATE TABLE emision_modificacion_eliminacion(
id SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
file_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
file_size MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
file MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL);

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)               Handles   Button2.Click
    Dim fs As FileStream
    Dim FileSize As UInt32
    Dim rawData() As Byte
    Dim cmd As New MySQLCommand
    Try
        fs = New FileStream("C:\Objetivos.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)            
        FileSize = fs.Length
        rawData = New Byte(FileSize) {}
        fs.Read(rawData, 0, FileSize)
        fs.Close()
        cmd = conxv.crear_consulta(cnn, "INSERT INTO emision_modificacion_eliminacion VALUES(NULL,'Objetivos.pdf', ?FileSize,?File)")
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?FileSize", FileSize)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?File", rawData)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("File Inserted into database successfully!", _
        "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
        cnn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error: " & ex.Message, "Error", _
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        cnn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that it's the BLOB causing you trouble?

You should not need to pass anything for the AUTO_INCREMENT type, so I would rewrite the SQL like this:

```
"INSERT INTO emision_modificacion_eliminacion VALUES('Objetivos.pdf', ?FileSize, ?File)"
```

It might be the `null` that is causing the error.

Comment: Yes i am, i'm gonna try with another transformation here